# Find k smallest numbers from n sorted arrays

Tags: merge, sorting

I have n Sorted arrays of different size. give K i need to find the first k smallest numbers.
int a[] = {10,20,30,40};
int b[]= {20,30,40};
int c[] ={-10,0};

If k = 1 then output should be an array = {-10}, k=2 then op= {-10,0} k = 4 {-10,0,10,20,20}

Ideas that I thought of:
1. maintain a min heap, but do I need to scan all the elements of all the remaining arrays?
2. maintain op Array of size K and then scan all the elements of all the array unless we come across an element greater than max in array "op"

Is there any way If I start thinking from columns?

Constraints: Merging all arrays and finding the first k is not good as arrays could be huge in size as well like million integers in a single array.

Comment: Added the constraints section.

Comment: I modified my response after your constraints were added; just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Using a basic merge (such as in a merge sort) will run in O(m) time (where m is the total number of elements), and from there you can just select the first k elements.

EDIT: After your ammendment about merging:

Another solution would be to iterate k times, and find the minimum of the first elements of each array (ie, if you have arrays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6], and [3, 4, 7, 8], you find the min(1, 2, 3). Add this min value to your solutions array (of the k smallest integers), and remove it from its respective array.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea ..

```
         List<int> new1 = new List<int>();
         List<int> testArr = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
         List<int> testArr1 = new List<int>() { -10, 0 };
     int[] newArr=   testArr.Concat(testArr1).ToArray();

     var s1 = (from i in newArr
              orderby i ascending
              select i);
     foreach (var x in s1)
     {
         new1.Add(x);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is

Converge all the sorted arrays into a single sorted array using  and then the answer is the k elements from the start of the new array. This, you can do by maintaining an index for each array from start and incrementing them as and when an element from that array is pushed into the result array. I have done this for two arrays and you can use the same further.

EDIT after constraint added:
Go through all the arrays and if any have length > k, truncate to length k (this could be a good tradeoff if each is a large array)

```
// Find K largest numbers in two sorted arrays
//Returns 0 on success and -1 in failure and c contains the resulting array


int k_largest(a, b, c, k) {
    int a_len = a.length;
    int b_len = b.length;
    if (a_len + b_len < k) return -1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int m = 0;

if(a[k] < b[0])
c=a;
else if (b[k] < a[0])
c=b;

/* (i<k) test below is to discard the rest of the elements of the arrays ,
using the sorted property of array */

    while (i < k && j < a_len && m < b_len) {
        if (a[j] < b[m]) {
            c[i] = a[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        } else {
            c[i] = b[m];
            i++;
            m++;
        }
    }

    if (i === k) {
        return 0;
    } else if (j < a_len) {
        while (i < k) {
            c[i++] = b[m++];
        }
    } else {
        while (i < k) c[i++] = a[j++];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do this again with a  =  resulting array and b = third array and so on

Comment: How about 1000 arrays of sise 1,2,3,...1000 and just consider all the elements in last array is all "-1".  In you solution for 100 smallest elements you would need to unncessarily merge the first 999 arrays.

Comment: @winuser123 answer edited. Atleast you have to test the k elements of each array. Otherwise you should modify the same above algorithm to use binary search. to find the point of change in direction..

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use your arrays like a stacks. You need to save a pointer to last used min value in each array and check all that pointers (3 pointers in your example) on each iteration. You need to do K iterations to get K values.

Here is a sample code on c#:

```csh
 int[] a = new int[] {10,20,30,40};
 int[] b = new int[] {20,30,40};
 int[] c = new int[] {-10,0};

 Dictionary<object, int> dic = new Dictionary<object, int>();
 dic.Add(a, 0);
 dic.Add(b, 0);
 dic.Add(c, 0);

 int K = 4;

 for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
 {
     var min = dic.Min(s => ((int[])s.Key)[s.Value]);
     var arr = dic.First(p => ((int[])p.Key)[p.Value] == min);
     int idx = arr.Value + 1;
     dic.Remove(arr.Key);
     if (((int[])arr.Key).Length > idx)
         dic.Add(arr.Key, idx);
     Console.WriteLine(min);
 }
```